# APACHE PIG : Invalid field projection. Projected field [Date] does not exist

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I know this issue is addressed before but probably my scenario is different and me being a novice isn't helping so seeking your guidance :)
I am learning PIG in a POC laptop setup. 
I have 4 text files each has around 50 columns including a date column. The 4 text files basically contain data for 4 different months (jan, feb, mar, apr).
I am trying to do a union of these 4 text files , save it in hdfs and then again from that UNION, I am trying to SPLIT the data into 4 different SPLITS by using the date column. 
So firstly I start with loading the 4 text files into 4 different variables -

```
jan = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/testing/201201hourly.txt' using PigStorage(','); 
feb = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/testing/201202hourly.txt' using PigStorage(','); 
mar = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/testing/201203hourly.txt' using PigStorage(','); 
apr = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/testing/201204hourly.txt' using PigStorage(',');
```

Then I do a UNION into another variable -

```
month_quad = union jan,feb,mar,apr;
```

Then I store the UNION into hdfs -

```
store month_quad into 'hdfs:/data/big/pigresult/month_quad';
```

So far so good, I can see the data in hdfs loaded as 64 mb blocks. The first part contains the columns and data.[pig screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsUrQ.png)
Hopefully I was able to successfully upload the link to a screenshot showing the data in hdfs :)

Now I try and do the split, using the following script -

```
split month_quad into split_jan IF ((Date,4,6) == '01'), split_feb
IF ((Date,4,6) == '02'), split_mar IF ((Date,4,6)=='03'),
split_apr IF ((Date,4,6) == '04');
```

I get the error when I run the above script, saying that  "Invalid field projection. Projected field [Date] does not exist."

```
2016-11-16 10:56:21,594 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025: 
<line 7, column 47> Invalid field projection. Projected field [Date] does not exist.
Details at logfile: /home/XXXXX/pig_1479273726378.log
```

I do recognize that I have not defined any datatype while loading the data in jan,feb,mar,apr but wasn't sure how to address it considering that the data that I have has 50 columns.
I am using hadoop 2.4. and Pig version 0.15.
Please guide me :)

EDIT : 
I was able to resolve this issue using the suggestion of @Amit by using positional notation. So my modified script for split is as follows. It did give me two warning but did the trick.

```
grunt> split month_quad into split_jan IF (SUBSTRING($1,4,6) == '01'),
>> split_feb IF (SUBSTRING($1,4,6) == '02'),                      
>> split_mar IF (SUBSTRING($1,4,6) == '03'),                      
>> split_apr IF (SUBSTRING($1,4,6) == '04');                      
2016-11-17 08:32:20,050 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_CHARARRAY 8 time(s).
2016-11-17 08:32:20,050 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning USING_OVERLOADED_FUNCTION 8 time(s).
```

Comment: have you tried replacing Date with month_quad::Date

Comment: Try `DESCRIBE month_quad` to find out what the schema for month_quad is.

Comment: I think you should use "Positional notation" to access the Date column as you do not have schema defined while declaring the Relation. Based on your screenshot it would be $1.

Comment: Thanks all for your generous responses. @NirmalRam Thanks Nirmal, I tried this and it again gave an error saying "month_quad::Date does not exist.

Comment: @RobinTrietsch Hi Robin, the schema is unknown.

Comment: @Amit . Hi Amit, your solution worked ! . I will edit my original post to share the modified script. Not sure how to mark your comment as the correct answer. Thanks so much !

Comment: Thank you and much appreciate your feedback. I believe I can post the same as answer so that you can mark it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use "Positional notation" to access the Date column as you do not have schema defined while declaring the Relation. Based on your screenshot it would be $1.

Answer (score 0):

In your declarative statements you need to add the field names.
your statements are like below:

jan = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/testing/201201hourly.txt' using PigStorage(',');

feb = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/testing/201202hourly.txt' using PigStorage(',');

...

...

This needs to be modified to

jan = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/testing/201201hourly.txt' using PigStorage(',') 
      AS (Date:chararray, field2:chararray, .....);

...
In fact the word "Date" is a reserved word and should be replaced with some other name, e.g., DateVal.

Also, a simple (Date,4,6) wont help. you need to add SUBSTRING(Date,4,6).
Note: SUBSTRING needs to be in upper case. Pig is case sensitive.

Comment: Hi Sukdeb, yeah as I said in my post, the data that I had is very wide and had 50 columns so datatyping all the columns did not look feasible.

Comment: Also agree on the SUBSTRING Comment. I actually had it added in the while I was coding but forgot to put it here when I was preparing the question. Still thanks so much for pointing it out ! :)

Comment: Since your Data is HDFS based you need to define all the columns as I mentioned.

Comment: alternatively, if you know the position of the data you can use $ parameters. e.g., $0 is first field, $1 is second field. so, if you date field is 3nd field, your if statement will be like IF (($3,4,6) ==  etc. etc..

Comment: @SukdebGanguli please use code formatting when responding to questions.

Comment: @SukdebGanguli Thanks Sukdeb - 'HDFS Data to have a mandatory requirement of defining all the column datatypes' is a good tip ! thanks so much again :)